# MariaDB error with MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA dbal option

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, mariadb, symfony4

I am currently working on a new project using Symfony 4.3 and MariaDB 10.4.22 (with WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04).

The database connection uses options with MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA to make secure connections.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
    ....
    options:
        !php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA: '%env(MYSQL_DB_ATTR_SSL_CA)%'
        !php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT: '%env(MYSQL_DB_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT)%'
```

The .env I received and which work on the DEV database (hence the MYSQL_DB_ATTR_SSL_CA as **false** )

```
MYSQL_DB_ATTR_SSL_CA='false'
MYSQL_DB_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT="%kernel.project_dir%/../path/to/crt.pem"
```

It works with our online database but I can't get it to work with my local database.
I am stuck with this error.
[image]

It **DOES** work if I comment the **!php/const:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA: '%env(MYSQL_DB_ATTR_SSL_CA)%'** in *doctrine.yaml* but it's not ideal.

So : I **don't** need to use a secure connexion on my localhost - these config are really only used in production. But I can't get it to work locally.
Is there a config MariaDB side I should touch ? Or a specific value for **MYSQL_DB_ATTR_SSL_CA** I should use ?

Every answer I've found online about this error seems to concern packet size and timeout which are already extremely maxed out on my database (hours and Go unit).

The error I got in my MariaDB error log :

```
2022-01-13 17:52:05 18 [Warning] Aborted connection 18 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: 'localhost' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
```

For info I have installed MariaDB following [their tarball installation tutorial](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-binary-tarballs/#installing-mariadb-as-not-root-in-any-directory) and it seems to work fine, only every making error once I uncomment the PDO options.

It does also  work with [MySQL 8](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04) without any configuration/problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge and solved it by conditionally setting the PDO option based on the existence of an environment variable and then prepending it to the doctrine configuration using an `Extension`.

Make the following changes to your project:

`src/config/packages/doctrine.yaml`

```yaml
parameters:
  env(MYSQL_SSL_CA): '' # Ensure the container parameter always exists.
```

`src/DependencyInjection/ParamHelper/php`

```php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class ParamHelper
{
    public static function getMySqlSslCa(ContainerBuilder $container): ?string
    {
        if (!$container->hasParameter('env(MYSQL_SSL_CA)')) return null;

        $escaped = $container->resolveEnvPlaceholders($container->getParameter('env(MYSQL_SSL_CA)'), true);

        return $container->getParameterBag()->resolveValue($container->getParameterBag()->unescapeValue($escaped));
    }
}
```

`src/DependencyInjection/MyExtension.php`

```php
use PDO;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;

class MyExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
    }

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if ($ca = ParamHelper::getMySqlSslCa($container)) {

            $container->prependExtensionConfig('doctrine', [
                'dbal' => [
                    'connections' => [
                        'default' => [
                            'options' => [
                                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => $ca,
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is set the `MYSQL_SSL_CA` environment variable on your production environment.

---

**PdoSessionHandler**

Additionally, if you're using the `PdoSessionHandler` to store your sessions, you also need to pass the PDO options to that constructor using a compiler pass.

`src/DependencyInjection/Compiler/PdoSslCaPass.php`

```php
use PDO;
use App\DependencyInjection\ParamHelper;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler;

class PdoSslCaPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!($ca = ParamHelper::getMySqlSslCa($container))) return;

        if ($container->hasDefinition(PdoSessionHandler::class)) {

            $d = $container->getDefinition(PdoSessionHandler::class);

            $options = array_merge_recursive($d->getArgument(1), ['db_connection_options' => [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => $ca]]);

            $d->setArgument(1, $options);
        }
    }
}
```

These examples shows you how to set `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA` but can be adjusted for any PDO option.